# MATLAB to web app

Tags: python, django, matlab, web-applications, octave

Hi I have a MATLAB function that graphs the trajectory of different divers (the Olympic sport diving) depending on the position of a slider at the bottom of the window. The file takes multiple .mat files (with trajectory information in 3 dimensions) as input. I am trying to put this MATLAB app on to the internet. What would be the easiest/most efficient way of doing this? I have experience programming in Python and little experience programming in Java.

Here are the options that I have considered:
1. MATLAB Builder JA (too expensive)
2. Rewrite entire MATLAB function into Java (not experienced enough in Java)
3. Implement MATLAB file using mlabwrapper and using Django to deploy into web app. (having a lot of trouble installing mlabwrapper onto OSX)
4. Rewrite MATLAB function into Python using SciPy, NumPy, and matlibplot and then using Django.

I do not have any experience with Django but I am willing to learn it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

A cheap and somewhat easy way (with limited functionality) would be:

Install MATLAB on your server, or use the MATLAB Compiler to create a stand alone executable (not sure if that comes with your version of MATLAB or not). If you don't have the compiler and can't install MATLAB on your server, you could always go to a freelancing site such as elance.com, and pay someone $20 to compile your code for you into a windows exe file.

Either way, the end goal is to make your MATLAB function callable from the command line (the server will be doing the calling) You could make your input arguments into the slider value, and the .mat files you want to open, and the compiled version of MATLAB will know how to handle this. Once you do that, have the code create a plot and save an image of it. (using getframe or other figure export tools, check out FEX). Have your server output this image to the client.

Tah-dah, you have a crappy low cost work around!

I hope this helps , if not, I apologize!

Comment: The license for MATLAB deployment products such as MATLAB Compiler prohibits compiling code for another organisation for money.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter about the money, it's just prohibited.

Comment: Oh, well good to know, thanks Sam! I didn't know that before, MATLAB in general seems to be very open to the distribution of compiled code so I figured this would be another case, but that is good info to know!

Comment: Someone else I talked to suggested using Octave as a possible solution. But after reading more into it, it seems like Octave will not be able to provide the web interface that I want (mainly the slider bar). Does any one experienced with Octave have any input?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just host the MATLAB code and sample .mat on a website for people to download and play with on their own machines if they have a MATLAB license.   If you are looking at having some sort of embedded app on your website you are going to need to rewrite your code in another language.  The project sounds doable in python using the packages you mentioned however hosting it online will not be as simple as running a program from your command line.  Django would help you build a website but I do not think that it will allow you to just run a python script in the browser.